# How to know which php page I am on?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am currently handed over a php project which was hosted by a different company before.My core domain is Java so everything related to PHP is new to me.When I run the project its difficult to know which PHP file the browser is showing since the URL does not show actual PHP filename due to 'URL rewriting'.I tried to remove the URL rewriting rules form .htaccess file but then application stopped working as I did dome mistake.In order to get the flow of project I just need to know which file is currently shown by the browser.Please help me achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo __FILE__;    
$included = get_included_files();
var_dump($included);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>
```

or use can use `print_r($_SERVER)`  what ever you want to know about the file and server

Answer (score 0):

You can use basename() and $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] to get current page file name

```
echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); /* It's returns The Current PHP File Name */
```

Answer (score 0):

How many rewrites are they in the .htaccess file ?
Each one of them should lead you to a specific file, that's the one you are looking for.

Comment: this is my .htaccess file `SetEnv MAGIC_QUOTES 0
SetEnv PHP_VER 5
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [L]
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

deny from someurl` If you can help me edit this I will be done.

Comment: It seems the index.php file is used to manage all the different includes.

There may be a code snippet there which manages the different includes. That's where you should echo the included file's name.

Comment: Its not possible to show the content of index of jsp here please help me as how do i send u the file contents

Answer (score 0):

PHP has Magic Constants that holds required information of its file :http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

```
__LINE__       The current line number of the file.
__FILE__       The full path and filename of the file with symlinks resolved. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned.
__DIR__        The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to dirname(__FILE__). This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory.
__FUNCTION__   The function name.
__CLASS__      The class name. The class name includes the namespace it was declared in (e.g. Foo\Bar). Note that as of PHP 5.4 __CLASS__ works also in traits. When used in a trait method, __CLASS__ is the name of the class the trait is used in.
__TRAIT__      The trait name. The trait name includes the namespace it was declared in (e.g. Foo\Bar).
__METHOD__     The class method name.
__NAMESPACE__  The name of the current namespace.
```

Just use it like this :

```
echo __DIR__;
```